Sort by name in an alphabetical order when returning in wrapper class
.
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static list<ProgramBrandTotalAmount> ReportWithTotalBrandOrder(string programId)
    {
        
        list<Program_Item__c> programBrandList =[SELECT Brand_Name__c 
                                                 FROM Program_Item__c 
                                                 WHERE Program_Item__c.Program__c = :programId];
       
        string uniqueBrandName;
        set<string> uniqueBrandNameSet = new set<string>();
        
        
        for (Program_Item__c brandList: programBrandList)
        {         
            uniqueBrandName = brandList.Brand_Name__c;
            uniqueBrandNameSet.add(uniqueBrandName);
        }
      

        list<ProgramBrandTotalAmount> itemstotalAmountListforAllBrandList = new list<ProgramBrandTotalAmount>();
        decimal totalBrandAmount =0;

        for(string brandName : uniqueBrandNameSet)
        {
            ProgramBrandTotalAmount itemstotalAmountListforBrand = new ProgramBrandTotalAmount();
            for(OrderDestinationItem__c orderdestinationItem :orderDestinationItemsList)
            {
                 
                if(brandName == orderdestinationItem.POS_Item__r.Brand__r.Brand_Name__c)
                {
                    totalBrandAmount += orderdestinationItem.Total_Line_Amount__c;
                    itemstotalAmountListforBrand.ProgramName = orderdestinationItem.OrderDestination__r.ProgramName__c;
                    itemstotalAmountListforBrand.BrandName = brandName;
                    itemstotalAmountListforBrand.ItemTotalAmountForBrand = totalBrandAmount;
                }
               
            }
            if(itemstotalAmountListforBrand.BrandName != null ){
                 
                itemstotalAmountListforAllBrandList.add(itemstotalAmountListforBrand);
            }
           
            totalBrandAmount =0;
         }
         return itemstotalAmountListforAllBrandList;

    }

    public class ProgramBrandTotalAmount
    {
        @AuraEnabled
        public string BrandName {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public string ProgramName {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public decimal ItemTotalAmountForBrand {get;set;}
    }

I have to sort by brand name before returning to LWC
I used sort() method but still no luck
Display should be based on the brand name but I don't know how to return when it comes to wrapper in an alphabetical order
Please help to me resolve this issue
Thanks in advance

Try with Comparable.
Something like this should be good start, you'd have to decide whether nulls should be first or last (although in your case I guess nulls would be bigger problem)
public class ProgramBrandTotalAmount implements Comparable {
    @AuraEnabled public string BrandName {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public string ProgramName {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public decimal ItemTotalAmountForBrand {get;set;}
    
    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        ProgramBrandTotalAmount other = (ProgramBrandTotalAmount) compareTo;
        if (String.isBlank(BrandName)) {
            return String.isBlank(other.BrandName) ? 0 : 1;
        }
        if (String.isBlank(other.BrandName)) {
            return -1;
        }
        return BrandName.compareTo(other.BrandName);
    }
}

and once you have it - call itemstotalAmountListforAllBrandList.sort() before returning it.

Now... the above is bit overkill, perhaps it'd be simpler to do this:
set<string> uniqueBrandNameSet = new set<string>();
for (Program_Item__c brandList: programBrandList)
{         
    uniqueBrandNameSet.add(brandList.Brand_Name__c);
}
List<String> sortedList = new List<String>(uniqueBrandNameSet);
sortedList.sort();

and later loop by that, for(string brandName : sortedList) instead of set... Your call. If in future you need to sort by brand and product - comparable would give you more flexibility.

And last but not least a true pro move would be to sort within SOQL if you can:
SELECT SUM(Total_Line_Amount__c), POS_Item__r.Brand__r.Brand_Name__c, OrderDestination__r.ProgramName__c
FROM OrderDestinationItem__c
GROUP BY POS_Item__r.Brand__r.Brand_Name__c, OrderDestination__r.ProgramName__c
ORDER BY POS_Item__r.Brand__r.Brand_Name__c,OrderDestination__r.ProgramName__c

